# Special Pricing calculator

Tags: java, html

I want to create a form or html file with special rate calculator.

For Example:

Start price for 1st 1kg = USD 20
Each Additional 500gms = USD 7.5

Once customer add their *KG : (Example 5kg), it should load Total amount : USD 80

is there any possible way to add this type of form, or any leads to guide me?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, congratulations on your first question! I am not sure what exactly you're asking for here though: is this a server-side code (Java) or client-side (JavaScript)?

Comment: im not a coder. im creating a website just like drag and drop, i want to add html iframe. its like a calculator

Comment: this is client side. when client add particular weight, price should show to client. starting weight is 1kg : usd 20, then every additional 500gms will be charged usd 7.5. if customer add  1.5kg, then price should show 27.5 usd

Comment: something like this slider also fine. https://www.jlankatech.com/#lead-block

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow Mohamed.  Typically you would try something first and then let us help you debug what is going wrong.  But here is something to help you get going.

I've hacked out a quick Javascript function to do the calculations you require.  You simply pass it an amount in GRAMS and it returns a value in dollars.  Experienced coders here will quickly note I could have coded this more elegantly but the purpose here is to show you how to code a function (this is good coding practice, code re-use) and use it, NOT show off how I can write something in a few lines of code.

To make this into the forms-based page you envision, replace the hardcoded  **CalculatePrice(5000)** call for 5 kilograms with a textbox on your page and do something like have a click method for a button call CalculatePrice() pass the value in your textbox.  Consider that you might need to warn your user to enter the value in grams OR modify the code in Calculate price to convert kilograms to grams before doing your math.

Again, my point here is to not write all of your code for you, just lay out some pointers to get you started.  Stack Overflow is about you trying things out and then asking for pointers,  but I believe this illustrates principals you are looking for :-)  It does the proper math in Javascript and shows you how to display a result on a page.  In the spirit of this forum, I leave it to you to experiment with this and turn it into a working app using the hints I've left.

If you paste the code below into notepad and save it as a web page and load it, you'll notice you get the correct value of 80 dollars you were looking for.

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
  function CalculatePrice(TotalGrams){
      var BaseUnits = 0;
      if (TotalGrams > 1000) {
        TotalGrams = TotalGrams - 1000;  // we've accounted for 1st kilo
        BaseUnits = 1;
      }

     var RemainingUnits = (TotalGrams) / 500;
     var retval = (BaseUnits * 20.0) + (RemainingUnits * 7.5);

     return retval;

  }

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = CalculatePrice(5000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not loading. May I know  how to add price range slider for website.
it should fixed rate at first 1kg (USD 20) then while sliding every 1kg it should be increased the price by USD 15. 

1st 1kg is USD 20 (Fixed amount), then additional KG will cost USD 15.
If I slide to 3KG it should show USD 50.

Comment: Hi Mohamed.  I don't understand  when you say it's not loading.  If you copy/paste the entire code into a text editor and save as an html file  then open  in a web browser, it will and illustrate the basic principals you are asking about.  As for the slider etc, you could integrate that into a UI just as I suggested passing the value from a textbox, but I humbly suggest you first experiment and understand the basic principles involved (such as the Javascript function/page interaction demo'd here).  SO is not a code writing service; you must make some effort to understand the basics yourself